# The $n$th derivative of complex function by $\theta$

Tags: complex-analysis

I've known the $n$-th derivative form of the complex function $f^{(n)}(z)$ by either $x$ or $y$ (Surely under hypothesis that $f$ is analytic)

For example $f^n(z) = (U_x^{(n)} + i V_x^{(n)} ) $ for  $f(z) = U(x,y) + i V(x,y)$ (Here $z= x+iy$)

I'm so curious that the form of the complex function if we differentiate it by only variable $r$ or two variables $r$ and $\theta$

I searched my book it just suggest only n-th derivative form differentiated by one variable $x,y$ respectively or mixed two variables $x$ and $y$

So, my question is Considering the analytic complex function $f(z) = U(r,\theta) + i V(r,\theta)  $ for $z =re^{i\theta}$

Then what is the form of the $f^n$($n$-th derivative) that  ${\partial ^n f \over \partial r^n}, {\partial ^n f \over \partial \theta^n}$  and  ${\partial ^n f \over \partial \theta^{i} \partial r^{j} }$ with $i+j =n$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to take derivatives with respect to real / imaginary coordinates, or with respect to $ r $ or $ \theta $, there's not really much use in even using the language of complex numbers.  All you're really doing is differentiating functions of multiple variables.

So instead of writing $ f(z) = U(r,\theta) + i V(r,\theta) $, we can simply write: $ f(x,y) = (u(x,y),v(x,y)) $.  Then your question boils down to, what is $$ \cfrac{\partial^n}{\partial r^n }\left[ f(\Phi(r,\theta)) \right] $$ where $ \Phi $ is the polar transformation $ \Phi(r, \theta) = (r \cos(\theta), r \sin(\theta)) $.  This is accomplished easily with the chain rule from multi-variable calculus, which I suggest you look up.  You are then free to translate this back to the language of complex numbers if it suits you.  But that doesn't seem particularly useful to me.  The differentiability properties of complex functions are only really useful when you're using the complex derivative $ d/dz $, which is not what you're asking about here.